# How will I post to a REST service using Rest Template in Spring / Java

Tags: java, spring, oauth, resttemplate

**curl 'https://polestar-pay/oauth2/token' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'code=Jf5wPTklRviNEhC_QbCobA&client_id=<>&client_secret=<>&grant_type=authorization_code&state=a1b2c3d4' --compressed**

Here I am trying to hit this curl using java programming.

```
 @RequestMapping("/token")

public String listUsers1121(HttpServletRequest request1)throws IOException {

    String code = request1.getParameter("code");
    String state = request1.getParameter("state");
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
     String url="https://persona.paytm.com/oauth2/token"; 
  MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,String();
  map.add("client_id", "api-int");
  map.add("client_secret", "251b2340185643ac7522ceee74287b5b");
  map.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
  map.add("code", code);
  map.add("state", state);


   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      headers.set("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate");



    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request =
new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

 List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
   messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
   restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

   LoginResponse response = (LoginResponse) restTemplate.postForObject(url,   request, LoginResponse.class);    


      System.out.println(response.loginToken);
    System.out.println(response.toString());
     System.out.println(request.getBody().toString());
    System.out.println(request.getHeaders());
     return response.toString();

       }
```

Using Curl I am getting the desired response(json output), but through this I am getting errors.  What am I doing wrong in the following code?

Comment: Please provide the full error mesage!

Comment: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."}